# Creating an array of numbers that add up to 1 with given length

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to use different weights for my model and I need those weights add up to 1 like this;

```
def func(length):
    return ['a list of numbers add up to 1 with given length']
```

`func(4)` returns `[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]`

The numbers should be linearly spaced and they should not start from 0. Is there any way to achieve this with `numpy` or `scipy`?

Comment: The range of the list in your example is only 0.3. Do you mean that the function takes as a param the _length_ of the list of weights it should produce? And those weights are linearly spaced, starting from (but not including) zero, as in the example?

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish Yes both of your assumptions are correct. I'll edit my post to be clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done quite simply using numpy arrays:

```
def func(length):
    linArr = np.arange(1, length+1)
    return linArr/sum(x)
```

First we create an array of length `length` ranging from `1` to `length`. Then we normalize the sum.

Thanks to Paul Panzer for pointing out that the efficiency of this function can be improved by using Gauss's formula for the sum of the first *n* integers:

```
def func(length):
    linArr = np.arange(1, length+1)
    arrSum = length * (length+1) // 2
    return linArr/arrSum
```

Comment: You can make this faster (at least for large `length`) by replacing the sum with `(length+1)*length//2`.

Comment: @Paul Panzer Excellent observation! I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

For large inputs, you might find that using `np.linspace` is faster than the accepted answer

```
def f1(length):
    linArr = np.arange(1, length+1)
    arrSum = length * (length+1) // 2
    return linArr/arrSum

def f2(l):
    delta = 2/(l*(l+1))
    return np.linspace(delta, l*delta, l)
```

Ensure that the two things produce the same result:

```py
In [39]: np.allclose(f1(1000000), f2(1000000))
Out[39]: True
```

Check timing of both:

```py
In [68]: %timeit f1(10000000)
515 ms ± 28.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [69]: %timeit f2(10000000)
247 ms ± 4.57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

It's tempting to just use `np.arange(delta, l*delta, delta)` which should be even faster, but this does present the risk of rounding errors causing the array to have lengths different from `l` (as will happen e.g. for `l = 10000000`).

If speed is more important than code style, it might also possible to squeeze out a bit more by using [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/):

```
from numba import jit

@jit
def f3(l):
    a = np.empty(l, dtype=np.float64)
    delta = 2/(l*(l+1))
    for n in range(l):
        a[n] = (n+1)*delta
    return a
```

```
In [96]: %timeit f3(10000000)
216 ms ± 16.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

While we're at it, let's note that it's possible to parallelize this loop. Doing so naively with Numba doesn't appear to give much, but helping it out a bit and pre-splitting the array into `num_parallel` parts does give further improvement on a quad core system:

```
from numba import njit, prange
@njit(parallel=True)
def f4(l, num_parallel=4):
    a = np.empty(l, dtype=np.float64)
    delta = 2/(l*(l+1))
    for j in prange(num_parallel):
        # The last iteration gets whatever's left from rounding
        offset = 0 if j != num_parallel - 1 else l % num_parallel
        for n in range(l//num_parallel + offset):
            i = j*(l//num_parallel) + n
            a[i] = (i+1)*delta
    return a
```

```
In [171]: %timeit f4(10000000, 4)
163 ms ± 13.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [172]: %timeit f4(10000000, 8)
158 ms ± 5.58 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [173]: %timeit f4(10000000, 12)
157 ms ± 8.77 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```